# Why Doesn't HTML5 Video Work In Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

Here is a little test code I'm trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Player Proof Of Concept</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="640" height="480" controls>
            <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works in Safari and Chrome. But in Firefox I get:

[image]

I use these files:

- http://zencoder-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/trailer_test.mp4
- http://zencoder-demo.s3.amazonaws.com/trailer_test.ogg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Browser format support

As far as I am aware, Firefox likes the [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org) format, as well as Ogg (It's reccomended to have all 3 options there for cross-browser compatibility). Also, support for MP4 or otherwise known as H.264 has only just been added, If you are in Linux, you need to run Nightly builds of Firefox 24 to get H.264 video playback, otherwise, it's supported from Firefox 22 and higher on Windows.[See this link here for more information on what supports the  tag types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support).

### Is your server set up correctly?

Your server may not be set up to support giving the client their correct MIME types. You can see how to fix this by adding the configuration variables shown at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Server_support) at the Mozilla Developer Network to your configuration.

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp Firefox supports ogg so why doesn't it play it? I have ogg file after mp4 there...

Comment: Is your server set up to give the client their correct MIME Type? Some servers like Apache or lighttpd may need some extra backend configuration to make sure this works, if your demo is hosted professionally, this is probably not the case, however. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Server_support

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It played well for chrome, safari, firefox (localhost). Once I moved it to my server, it couldn't play anymore. After much countless tries, I came across this post http://voice.firefallpro.com/2012/03/html5-audio-video-mime-types.html

and added

`AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm`

to my .htaccess. It worked.